« Dès » ou « depuis » ?
Je ne suis pas sûre de devoir dire

Dès son premier roman, elle a publié deux autres livres.

ou

Depuis son premier roman, elle a publié deux autres livres.

Puis-je utiliser les deux formes avec une différence de sens ? Ou l'une d'elles n'est-elle pas correcte ?
Sur « dès » et « depuis », le livre Grammaire expliquée du français. Niveau intermédiaire dit:

Tous deux marquent le point de départ dans le temps, mais dès suppose que l'action ou l'événement s'est produit immédiatement. 
[...] 
Depuis marque aussi le commencement mais insiste, de plus, sur l'idée de durée d'une action ou d'un événement qui continue.

J'ai vu cette autre question, mais elle ne m'a pas aidée.

Ces deux phrases ont un sens différent.

Dès son premier roman, elle a publié deux autres livres.

Le jour où elle a publié son premier livre, elle a aussi publié deux autres livres.

Depuis son premier roman, elle a publié deux autres livres.

Entre le jour où elle a publié son premier livre et aujourd'hui, elle a publié deux autres livres.
La deuxième forme est très probablement celle attendue. Le style de la première laisse aussi à désirer. J'aurais plutôt écrit : Dès la publication de son premier roman, […]
Dès est similaire à une fois (once, una vez) alors que depuis correspond à since, desde.
